# Let $a_n= Sup_{k \geq n} x_k$ and $b_n=Inf_{k\geq n}x_k$ then $\{a_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence and...

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_n= Sup_{k \geq n} x_k$ and $b_n=Inf_{k\geq n}x_k$ then

1) $\{a_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence 
2) $\text{Inf}a_n=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n$

**My attempt:**
1) For prove $\{a_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence we need prove $a_n>a_{n+1}$.

Let $\{x_n\}$ a sequence. We know by hypothesis for all $k\geq n$ we have:  $a_n= Sup_{k \geq n} x_k$

Here i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

For part 2) i don't have a idea of how attack the exercise.

Comment: How do you define $\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n$?

Comment: Suppose there are people in the room and you write on the board the height of the tallest of them. Then you choose a random person and ask him to leave. Then you write the height of the tallest person from those who are still in the room. Can the second number be bigger than the first one?

Comment: The supremum and infimum of the set of limit points i use this definition @JoséCarlosSantos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that $(x_n)$ is bounded. I will leave the case where it is unbounded to you. If $A \subset B \subset \mathbb R$ then $\inf\, B \leq \inf\, A$. Taking $A=\{x_n,x_{n+1}...\}$ and $B=\{x_{n+1},x_{n+2}...\}$ we see that $a_n \geq a_{n+1}$. This proves 1).

Now by defintion of infimum it follows that for each $n$ there exist $k_n \geq n$ such that $a_n-\frac 1 n <x_{k_n}<a_n$. Since $(a_n)$ is decreasing we can write $\inf_n a_n$ (call it $a$) as $\lim a_n$. Now apply squeeze theorem to see that $x_{k_n} \to a$, Hence $a$ is  a limit point of $(x_n)$. To prove that it is the larges limit point let $c$ be an limit point. If possible let $c >a$. Pick  a number $b$ in $(a,c)$. Let $x_{k_n} \to c$. Then (by definition of $a_{k_n}$) we have $a_{k_n} \geq x_{k_n}>b$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Hence $a \geq b>a$ which is a contradiction.